# Self-consistent updates of form fields

Tags: javascript

For a simple calculation tool, I want several user input fields that update other fields when they are changed in a consistent manner.

Let's assume the following calculation tool consisting of four fields:

- start value
- stop value
- span field
- center.

If the user enters a start value and a stop value, the center is computed by (start+stop)/2, the span by (stop-start). Vice-versa, the start and the stop value can be computed from center and span.

I want the user to be able to change any of the four fields and update the others accordingly.

The obvious solution is to write event handlers that update the other fields as shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57701351). However, this requires me to program the same arithmetics four times. Therefore, I am wondering whether there is another way to define the arithmetic only once and then enforce the consistency between the values or in other words an approach that scales better for many fields.

Answer (score 0):

Nice question, but to be honest, I don't think the perfect solution, you dream of, exists.

Think about it: Changing the span is something completely different from changing the start.

See it as an equation with four variables of which three are known. How to calculate the fourth? It will be different for every variable.

Answer (score 0):

> This requires me to program the same arithmetics four times.

In your case, it's actually only two times:

- if start or stop change, you compute center and span from them.
- if center or span change, you compute start and stop from them.

It could be more complicated of course if you had different dependencies (but also more confusing to the user), or it even might be dynamic where you allow the user to "lock" a set of values and then have the others change depending on the locked values and the input.

> I am wondering whether there is another way to define the arithmetic only once and have it scale for many fields

Yes, you can use a symbolic maths library to define the equation(s). Then for each input event handler, you solve the system of equations for the outputs and plug in the fixed values to get the new values of the dependent fields. You still will have to define what fields are treated as input and what fields are treated as output for every individual event, though.